# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus problem

Tags: calculus, integration

I don't understand the intuition behind this.  Why can we just plug in $x$ for $t$ here and that gives us the result?  I thought I was understanding the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but I don't see how it applies here.  I thought the Theorem mainly stated that the area under a function can be found by taking the the value of the anti derivative over the specified interval. It doesn't make sense to me why we just plug in $x$ and voila that's our answer.

$$\frac {d}{dx} \int_{a}^{x} (t^3 + 1) \ dt = x^3 +  1$$

Comment: If $F(x)$ is the antiderivative function of $f(x)=t^3+1$, then $\int_a^x t^3+1dt=F(x)-F(a)$. So the L.H.S becomes $\frac{dy}{dx}F(x)$ which is $x^3+1$.

Comment: Evaluate that integral, and take the derivative with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the function $\,t^3+1\,$ is continuous (and derivable) everywhere, it has a primitive function $\,G(t)\,$in any finite interval. Using the FTC , write

$$\int_a^x(t^3+1)dt=G(x)-G(a)\\\Longrightarrow \frac{d}{dx}{\left(\int_a^x(t^3+1)dt\right)}=\frac{d}{dx}{(G(x)-G(a))}=G'(x)=x^3+1$$

Comment: So we just get rid of the G(a) because we are differentiating with respect to x?

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff, thanks.

Comment: Of course, @ordinary.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to this

Comment: @ordinary The integral has a fixed lower bound $a$ and a changing upper bound $x$. $G(a)$ is therefore constant, and differentiating it would yield $0$.

Comment: As new as you may be, you must know that **anything** different from the variable wrt which we derivate is to be considered a constant.

Comment: @FrenzY DT Ah thanks for adding that, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 4):

The **Fundamental Theorem of Calculus** doesn't talk about geometrical results, but about the "fundamental" relation between the operation of integration and that of differentiation. Namely, it says the following:

> **THEOREM**. Let $f$ be a continuous over $[a,b]$. Define $F$ on $[a,b]$ by
>
> $$F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) dt$$
>
> Then $F$ is differentiable, and $F'(x)=f(x)$.

The corollary is

> **COROLLARY** Let $f$ be continuous over $[a,b]$ and $f=g'$ for some $g$.
>
> Then
>
> $$\int_a^b f(t)dt=g(b)-g(a)$$

Note we can find this reversed in the books (One is the theorem and the other the corollary, or one is called FTC 1 and the other FTC 2). I recommend you read these two questions some users already asked about FTC:

- [Understanding the relation between differentiation and integration.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116620/understanding-the-relationship-between-differentiation-and-integration/116984#116984)
- [How do explain FTC to my teacher?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168876/how-do-i-explain-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-to-my-teacher/168887#168887)

Comment: $F$  is differentiable at the points where $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @Masacroso Yes, of course. There. ;)