# Limits of a definite integrals (Demidovich)

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

I'm being unable to solve this exercise from the Demidovich's book where you need to evaluate limits involving definite integrals where the interval of integration is defined as a function of x.

How do I approach this kind of problems? Here I list one specific problem from Demidovich's book:
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{\int_{0}^{x} (\arctan (t))^2 dt}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

Could you please demonstrate the approach on the problem above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit in question is an indeterminate form (in this case $\frac\infty\infty$), so you would apply L'Hopital's rule. To differentiate the numerator, use the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/182691/215011).

Comment: I applied L'Hospital's rule and I'm left with $\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{(\arctan(x))^2}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}$. How do I proceed?

Comment: The denominator tends to $1$ because you can factor out $x$ from both top and bottom. As for the numerator, consult a plot of the arctan function to see that $\arctan x$ tends to $\pi/2$ as $x\to\infty$

Comment: Yes, I see. Everything is clear to me now. Thanks.