# Visualization of relation between integration and derivative operations

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

If I have a function $f(x)$ and I find the derivative I will get $f'(x)$.
Furthermore, if I do the integration of the derivative $f'(x)$, as a result I will get again my original function $f(x)$.

What I do not understand is a **relation** between integration and derivative operations.
For me, the derivative is an operation where we calculate the slope of a function, and integration is an area under a curve.

But, if we take an example where $f(x) = x^3$. The derivative is $f'(x) = 3x^2$. If we do the integration of the $3x^2$ we will get our $x^3$ back again. But, $3x^2$ is some function, and if we do the integration on it, we should get its area under the $3x^2$. Is it possible to visualize that relation between derivative and integral operation, because I do not see it from the graph below?

[image]

Comment: I was aware of that question, and although mine is similar, it's not the same. I want to see whether is possible to visualize that relationship given on the graph above, without using many (or any) equations.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to visualize it just based on the graph.  I know it's a disappointing answer, but the derivative/integral relationship is easier to understand algebraicly (and through the answers on the linked thread) than through looking at the graphs.  Especially if you overlay the two graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While many mathematicians often like to forget about *units*, understanding units will be really helpful here.

Some transformations, such as $f(x) \mapsto f(x) + 3$, $f(x) \mapsto 4f(x)$, and $f(x) \mapsto f(x+3)$, are easy to understand visually looking at the graphs.  Because the start function and the end function have the same units, it *makes sense* to plot them on top of one another on the same axes.

The transformation $f \mapsto f'$ is not like this.  If $f$ has units of meters, and $x$ is seconds, then $f'$ has units of meters per second.  This means that "comparing" them as you have done by overlaying them on top of each other is nonsense.  For example, you can't glean anything from the fact that 5 meters per second is larger than 3 meters, or from the fact that 2 meters per second equals 2 meters.

The relationship between $f$ and $f'$ is not understood by comparing one directly to the other, but rather by understanding what features of $f$ correspond to features of $f'$.  Draw $f$ and $f'$ on *separate pairs of axes*, and there are many features of import, many of which you probably know: for instance, zeros of $f'$ are local min- and maxima of $f$.

In short, **the fundamental relationship between the two functions is not of a nature that you can just compare one to the other by overlaying their graphs.**  Your problem arises because you *expect* the graphs of $f$ and $f'$ to be visually comparable in an obvious way, which they are not.  Instead, you must be willing to accept a different way of understanding the relationship than the one you are looking for.  (See [the answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116620/understanding-the-relationship-between-differentiation-and-integration) which has already been linked.)  It would be like trying to understand how to multiply two numbers $x$ and $y$ by only looking at the values of $2^x$ and $2^y$.